# Why doesn't my code compile?

Tags: f#

```
let sub (m:double[],n:double[]) : double[]=
    [| for i = 0 to Array.length m -1 do m.[i]-n.[i] |]
```

Error   1   This value is not a function and cannot be applied  E:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\curve intersection\newton\Module1.fs 27  21  newton

But, this is ok:

```
let a = [| "a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f" |]

for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    System.Console.WriteLine(a.[i])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spaces around a minus sign matter:

```
f -1   // means f(-1)
```

calls the function `f` with an argument of `-1` (unary minus).  Whereas

```
n - 1
```

and

```
n-1
```

are subtraction.

The compiler error reflects that

```
Array.length m -1
```

parses as

```
(Array.length m)(-1)
```

as though it is expecting the first expression to return a function, which will then be applied to the value `-1`.  Since length actually returns an `int`, you get the error message that says that an integer is not a function and cannot be applied to the argument `-1`.

Comment: As an editorial aside, I think this is the only place where I find significant whitespace to be surprising/annoying.  In every other case, I love it.

Comment: Maybe if I took the time to write detailed answers people would accept them more. :)

Answer (score 3):

This compiles:

```
let sub (m:double[], n:double[]) : double[] =
    [| for i = 0 to Array.length m - 1 do yield m.[i] - n.[i] |]
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your list/array comprehension is wrong.

you either use `->` as a short cut:

```
let a = [1;2;3]
[| for i in a -> i |]
```

or formally write `yield`:

```
[| for i in a do yield i |]
```